# C# Message box multiple display in a row

Tags: c#, database, winforms, foreach, messagebox

I'm doing this code for list view to database i wanted to save all the columns, it saves but it display a messagebox in each row. Can somebody help me out to fix this i want to display only one messagebox when the button's click.
So here is my code

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
{
    string condense = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=''";
    string milk = "insert into cashier.sales(Cashier,Orders,Quantity,Size,Price,Date) values ('" + this.cashier.Text + "','" + li.SubItems[0].Text + "','" + li.SubItems[1].Text + "','" + li.SubItems[2].Text + "','" + li.SubItems[3].Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value + "');";
    MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(condense);
    MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(milk, conDatabase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cashier.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the Notes. ", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    else
    {
        conDatabase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

        MessageBox.Show("Order has been added successfully  ", "Order!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

         total.Text = "";
         amount.Text = "";
         change.Text = "";
         while (myReader.Read())
         {
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Put your messagebox.show OUTSIDE of the foreach loop.

Comment: Now you say for each row display message box...

Comment: omg. thankyou so much.

Comment: It's a simple logic that your message box display code is inside the loop. You need to keep it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `MessageBox`outside of your loop

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
    {

        string condense = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=''";
        string milk = "insert into cashier.sales(Cashier,Orders,Quantity,Size,Price,Date) values ('" + this.cashier.Text + "','" + li.SubItems[0].Text + "','" + li.SubItems[1].Text + "','" + li.SubItems[2].Text + "','" + li.SubItems[3].Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value + "');";
        MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(condense);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(milk, conDatabase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cashier.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill the Notes. ", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            conDatabase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

            total.Text = "";
            amount.Text = "";
            change.Text = "";
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
    }

MessageBox.Show("Orders has been added successfully  ", "Order!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```